# how to fix that chinese-mainland-android-devloper's virtual device can't display google-map normally?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I am a developer from mainland China and I have already

- set up google-play services
- configured google-api-key.
- can access foreign sites

In the beginning, I felt this is the problem of my application code due to which google-map isn't displayed (blank area). To verify it, I downloaded google official map-app-demos and ran it. The result is the same - displays blank area!

So I can confirm that the problem is due to my location and not my application code. This is the log:

```
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
```

Although I have come over the firewall, why is it still happening? Is there something, I am missing?

Can you help me to fix this problem? My aim is just to display google map.

Comment: a good background of your problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9Di-UVC-_4

Comment: in a nutshell - no other than Chinese companies are allowed to make a map of China,  Google is not a Chinese company

Comment: @Taier thank you, i have already resolved the problem.two steps:1.make sure the simulator can access non-chinese site(most diffcult,note:simulator can access foreign site,not just pc).2.make sure the simulator has installed google services.i hope my expriences can help others who meet a same trouble as mine.

Comment: good to know, please answer to your own question with that so next person to face it would have an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have already resolved this problem.
two steps:1.make sure the simulator can access non-chinese site(most diffcult,note:simulator can access foreign site,not just pc).2.make sure the simulator has installed google services.
Note:only the emulator named "雷电" can access foreign site in china depend on my own expriences.